# laravel 5 mime image validation throws exception when uploading an mp3 or mp4

Tags: php, image, validation, laravel, laravel-5

ok.. i don't know how many of you had this problem in Laravel.. i could not find any solution for this.

i'm validating the uploaded image using Validator by setting rules with mime type jpeg, bmp and png. 
I flash an error message if it's not of these types.

It works fine for all file types, but when i upload an mp3 or mp4 it shows an exception in my controller.

MyImageController.php Code :

```
    public function addImageDetails()

    {

    $input = Request::all();

    $ID = $input['ID'];
    $name = $input['name'];

    $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));

    $rules = array('image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'); 


    $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {

     \Session::flash('flash_message_error','Should be an Image');

      return view('addDetails');
    }

    else {

         //If its image im saving the ID, name and the image in my DB
     }
```

This is the error that i get when i upload an mp3 or mp4

```
       ErrorException in MyImageController.php line 25:
       Undefined index: ID
```

validating all other file types like [.txt, .doc, .ppt, .exe, .torrent] etc..

Comment: Perhaps `$input['id']` ?

Comment: found out that the problem is not with mp3 or mp4.. itz with the size i upload.. if it's too large then php has empty post variable it seems.. thats why i'm gettin Undefined index : ID..

Comment: That's great. Then you shall post it as answer.

Comment: still i don't know how to solve this.. do i need to change php upload settings.. can you please.. help me out by giving a fine answer..

Comment: Do you want to increase the file size or handle the error ?

Comment: well i wanted to handle the error.. can u also say how to increase the size too.. thanks for the quick replies.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you Allocate the `Request::all();` to the variable `$input`

```
$input = Request::all();
```

Then you should check whether it has any value

```
if (isset($input['ID']))
```

If the condition satisfies the you shall allow it to proceed further steps else you should return the view with your error message like the code given below.

```
if (isset($input['ID'])) 
{
    $ID = $input['ID'];
    $name = $input['name'];
    $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
}
else
{
    return view('addDetails')->with('message', 'Image size too large');;
}
```

**Update :**

Here you check for image type

```
if (isset($input['ID'])) 
{
if (Input::file('image')) 
{
    $ID = $input['ID'];
    $name = $input['name'];
    $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
else
{
    return view('addDetails')->with('message', 'Uploaded file is not an image');;
}
}
else
{
    return view('addDetails')->with('message', 'Image size too large');;
}
```

Comment: thanks alot :) but still this logic will also show the message for larger non-image files know?? finding out a way..

Comment: Yes, we can change it.. do you want to show other error message for larger non-image file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this clean code:

```
public function addImageDetails(Request request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => ['required', 'image']
    ]);

    //If its image im saving the ID, name and the image in my DB

}
```

There is a rule called `image` that could be helpful for you in this situation

Comment: i tried this too.. but it didn't work.. found out that the problem is with the size of my uploaded file.. if it's too large it throws an error.. can u suggest me a way to solve this?

Comment: Consider edit `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file to set enough limit size for file uploading

Comment: upload_max_filesize in php.ini file is 64M.. but i can't upload size with 3 mb even.. any ideas??

Comment: take a look to `post_max_size` var size

Comment: yep :) setting post_max_size works.. but i should handle that by checkin the uploaded file's size..

Comment: then add the rule `'max:3000'`